# java double is not calculating correctly

Tags: java, double

I'm making this program for a class and I need to guess a number's cube root. Here's my code:

```
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

//sets the guess at 1.0
guess = 1.0;

//whether or not the guess is close to N
while (guess * guess * guess <= N ){

     double show = (guess + ((1/3) * ((N / (guess * guess)) - guess)));
     System.out.println(show);
     guess = show;
     continue;

}
```

However, every time I run this program, the double show is always set to the value 1. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Just as a note, there's never any reason to put `continue` at the end of a loop like that, the loop will continue on its own anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1/3 = 0
```

because 1/3 is integer division and that is always 0. It should be

```
1.0/3.0
```

Comment: i think this helped, thanks a lot! I'll mark it as the answer soon as the time limitation passes

Comment: Or 1.0/3 or 1/3.0 or (double)1/3 or 1/(double)3 or (double)1/(double)3. No 'always' about it.

Answer (score 3):

The constant expression `(1/3)` is calculated using integer arithmetic, leaving 0. Try using `(1.0/3.0)`. Or alternately,

```
 double show = (guess + (((N / (guess * guess)) - guess)) / 3.0);
```

Comment: The alternate version works because there are already doubles in the term so it got "upgraded". To be on the safe side (and not have to think about it every time), use 3.0 even there.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll change that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is integer division. `1 / 3 = 0`.

Change it to `1.0 / 3.0`

BTW, there is no point for the `continue` statement...